# Lots of if statements

Tags: android, if-statement

I want to make some kinda dictionary,But not exactly a dictionary,

I have two text views, One for the word, The other one for the meaning.

I have two Buttons which they change an integer's number

And finally I have lots of if, For Example:

```
(if i==1){

txt1.setText("x");

txt2.setText("y");

}

(if i==2){

txt1.setText("n");

txt2.setText("m");

}
```

Q1: Its better with switch right?

Q2: Where should I put those Switch? In each Button's ClickListener ?

Q3: Can you suggest a better way to do that?

Comment: If you have more than 3 if clauses, you could always consider using a Switch Statement.

Comment: @fractalwrench thanks,can you answer my second question :D

Comment: You are manually coding a table with columns `(id, text1, text2)`. You can replace the whole construct by a search through said table by id (use a `Map` or even sqlite when there are many values).

Comment: @dhke Thanks for your respond but I dont want to use SQLite

Comment: @Sahand.Setoodeh Then use a Map? When there are few values, even a simple list is sufficient.

Comment: @dhke you mean HashMap?

Comment: @Sahand.Setoodeh `Map` is the generic interface for key-value stores. `HashMap` is a specific implementation of that interface. In your case: Are the indexes consecutive (no gaps)? If so: create a class for your text pairs and use a list of those classes.

Comment: @dhke Yeah,Got It.Thanks so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch is definitely a better option.

You can have a common API that will handle this logic like:

```
toggleText(int i){
    switch(i){
        case 1:
            txt1.setText("x");
            txt2.setText("y");
            break;
        case 2:
            txt1.setText("n");
            txt2.setText("m");
            break;
    }
}
```

Then u can call this API from ur button cick:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener{
     @Override
     onClick(){
          toggleText(pass your value here)
     }
});
```

Let me know if u need any help.

Comment: Well I found switch is a better option ,by the way can you tell me how exactly make toggleText?

Comment: You can create a method in your activity and you can call this method from your button's onClickListener. And this method should have the respective switch statements. I'll update my answer to reflect the same.

Answer (score 0):

1. Switch is good option than if else
2. Make a function and put all switch conditions in it and call that function on button click

Comment: Can you explain a little bit about it,or give an example?